# Нет соединения с MySql в Delphi

Tags: delphi, база-данных, mysql

Доброй ночи! Быть может, я чего-то не понимаю, но для соединения с удаленной базой данных SQL нужно сделать запрос. Собственно сама БД хранится на сайте. Пытаюсь подконнектиться к ней, дабы проверить соединение через `novicat`, но не могу). Выдает ошибку:

> 2003 - Can't connect to MySql server on 'myip' (10060).

Во всех примерах указан какой-то Microsoft Mysql Server, а если его собственно нету, на сайте, а есть только phpmyadmin и все? Сформировать и работать с БД то я смогу, а вот подконнектиться к ней ну никак не могу. 
В общем, прошу помощи разрешить данную проблему.

P.S. Всем спасибо, кто не поленился прочитать мои нубские вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виртуальные хосты очень неохотно октрывают достут к MYSQL извне.
Вам нужно приобрести хост или с персоналным MYSQL с полным доступом (чтоб самому открыть).
Но это всеравно опасно.

Лучше попробовать реолизавать то что вы хотите с помошю XML, или сделать SOAP сервер на PHP или JAVA или что еше ваш хостер прозволяет для доступа к базе.

А из делфи подключаться уже к SOAP-у.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на форуме вашего хостинга. Может, уже кто-то сталкивался с вашей проблемой. У моего хостинг провайдера все подробно описано, как подключаться через `Navicat` и туннель.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пожалуй, напишу в тех. поддержку хостинга.

Comment: В тех. поддержке написали, что нужно открыть удаленный доступ к MySQl какому-нибудь ip, но если мне нужно, чтобы с любого компьютера можно было бы получить запрос от БД, то это противоречит безопасности. Поэтому подскажите, как это все можно реализовать? Мне не нужны сложнейшие таблицы, а всего лишь 2-3 с парочкой атрибутов и все.

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге MySQL есть строка "разрешить доступ из вне для всех".

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, где эта строка. Посмотрел в разных настройках и ничего не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, поподробнее куда мне пройти. Сейчас я нахожусь на главной странице phpMyAdmin.

Comment: ищи строку bind-address, это я смотрю в my.cnf а как оно в phpMyAdmin я не знаю(

Answer (score 0):

По идей доступ к БД открываеться с помощью "Привелегий", в phpMyadmin,(вкладка "Privelegies"),Заходите туда и:

1-добавляете нового пользователя

2-при выборе доступа пропишите
   [ИМЯ_Пользователя]@[Ваш ip]
   ,(например ваш адрес 89.89.89.89,и
   имя пользователя саша,то получиться

> саша@89.89.89.89

)
Вроде так я думаю..А если не получиться, то тогда к хостеру надо обращаться,к сожалению..